# ConfigError when AWS is configured in a different file (using DynamoDB locally)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to use DynamoDB with Alexa SDK by configuring AWS in a separate file.

I have tested that my Alexa skill works by configuring AWS within `index.js`:

```
const Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");
const AWS   = require("aws-sdk");
setupDynamoDB();

// my code ...

function setupDynamoDB (alexa) {
    AWS.config.update({
        region: 'us-east-1',
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'
    });
}
```

I thought it would be fancier if I create the `setupDynamoDB()` function somewhere else and import it, so I tried it.

**index.js**:

```
const Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");
const AWS   = require("./dynamodb").setupDynamo();
```

**dynamodb.js**:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

module.exports = {
    setupDynamo: function (alexa) {
        AWS.config.update({
            region: 'us-east-1',
            endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'
        });
    }
    return AWS;
};
```

Even with the `return` statement my skill doesn't seem to be able to access the table, which is odd because it seems like (to me, at least) I am defining an already configured AWS object instead of running the two step process (define AWS *then* configure).

I am using `bespoken-tools` proxy to test the skill and the error message I get is:

```
get error: {
    "message": "Missing region in config",
    "code": "ConfigError",
    "time": "2017-04-15T08:38:55.858Z"
}
```

I haven't tried whether this works on Alexa Simulator because my goal is to make it work with `bst` anyway. I'm also trying to exploit the built-in support for DynamoDB that Alexa SDK has, hence the simplified configuration process (pretty much all other resources I could find were creating a `DynamoDB` object, which I don't intend to do).

What am I doing wrong here? The only explanation I can come up with is that the AWS object being returned is different from the one that *would have* been returned had I defined and called `setupDynamoDB()` within `index.js`... But I can't figure out why that would be the case.

---

EDIT: I figured out a fix, but I'm not sure if it is an intended behavior. Basically, `return`ing the `AWS` object doesn't work, but declaring *and* `return`ing the `Alexa` object does. See below for the code.

**index.js**:

```
const Alexa = require("./dynamodb").setupDynamo();
```

**dynamodb.js**:

```
exports.setupDynamo = function (alexa) {
    const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    AWS.config.update({
        region: "us-east-1",
        endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
    });
    const Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");
    return Alexa
};
```

So essentially, the updated configurations for the `AWS` object is lost upon being `return`ed. Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is the order of your calls. If you make your call to setupDynamo BEFORE the call to require('alexa-sdk'), then it should work.

The alexa-sdk immediately begins using Dynamo, so any configuration changes need to be done first.

Comment: Actually it was something else (I just figured it out). So instead of returning `AWS` in **dynamodb.js**, if I declare an `Alexa` object inside the function _and_ `return` it, the code works. I have edited my question with a full snippet of this change. I'm not sure if this is an expected behavior, as it seems that when `AWS` is returned from a function, the updated configurations seem to get lost.